# Material UI Tabs not rendering properly on server

Tags: material-ui

I am having a problem using the "Tabs" component: https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/ In fact, when developing locally, the rendering of the component is fine.  But pushing to the server, it looks weird (with differences in the borders on each side of the bar).

Moreover: when refreshing the page in which it has been embedded or browsing manually to this page, the whole template is broken all of a sudden!

I tried generating a build folder locally and launching the page from that build, and fell back on the same problem.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I saw that your "build" is not work even in local development. That's mean it should not work on the production, of course.
The thing is, what is your actual "build" action? Depends on what library/framework you use, but basically with Material-UI, most popular problem comes from not load some CSS before using it's components.
Please read here first: https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/#server-rendering
Just in case you use Gatsby, read here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/.

I'm using Gatsby and use this following config to fix some CSS issues.

```
stylesProvider: {
 injectFirst: true,
}
```

Hope this help.